# How exclude 3 latest posts of a category in query_posts

Tags: query-posts, exclude

I am newbie in wordpress development, and usually I use query posts with simple commands.

I have a slider in home page which shows 3 latest posts form 'featured' category.
I have also a news box category which shows 3 latest posts form 'news' category.

for rest of my home page I want to show 10 posts. but want to exclude 3 latest posts form 'featured' category and 'news' category becuase I don't want posts be repetitive (duplicate) in home page.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you coded so far? Please post your work. Also note query_posts is not recommended.

Comment: `query_posts` breaks the main query object on which the content of a page relies. There is no use in posting any kind of solution when you are using `query_posts` on the affected page :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
$excluded_posts = array();

// select first 3 featured posts ordered by date

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'category_name'          => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true, // or maybe not?
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
    $excluded_posts[] = get_the_ID();
}

wp_reset_postdata();

// select first 3 news ordered by date

$args['category_name'] = 'news';

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
    $excluded_posts[] = get_the_ID();
}

wp_reset_postdata();

$args = array (
    'post__not_in'              => $excluded_posts,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'       => true,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
    // finally loop with last 10 without last 3 news and featured posts
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts`, much cleaner

Comment: Do not replace the main query with a custom one

Comment: Thanks Emetrop, It is misunderstood. My site have many categories: Featured, news, technology, Startup, ... I want to show 10 latest published posts per page from all categories, but do not show 3 latest posts of 'featured' category and 3 latest posts of 'news' category.(because 3 latest posts of 'featured' category and 3 latest posts of 'news' category exist in other section of home page)

Comment: Asghar I edited the code right now. It'll work but it's not the best practice as Pieter Gossen said, I'll edit it later.

Comment: Thank you Emertop, it works fine. I do not know why wp-pagenavi is not working with the query you wrote.  I put <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?> before the  wp_reset_postdata(); but nothing is displayed.